# Where to look for customizing

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm customizing a code for a button:

```
<button type="submit" 
        id="buttonSaveAsDraft" 
        class="primary preview next button buttonAction" 
        title="Save and exit MessageCoder" 
        value="1">Save</button>
```

Upon clicking the button, it's taking me to a different website which I want to disable. In order to figure out, I started looking at the CSS used by this button ( I figured out about the CSS using dreamweaver). So basically, I'm doing control + F in dreamweaver and looking for the id `buttonSaveAsDraft` and classes `"primary, preview, next, button, buttonAction"` in the CSS but it's not showing up.

1) Am I doing something wrong here?

2) The CSS is a very long messed up file. Is there any way to properly format it and take a look at it?

Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: CSS has hardly anything to do with “upon clicking the button, it's taking me to a different website”.

Comment: Then based on the above code, what do you think?

Comment: It's not a link. Look for the form that contains the button. The action of the form controls where the page "goes" when submitted. If you don't want the button to submit the form, remove the form, change the type of button, change the action of the form, etc.

Comment: Thank you, I found it at 1<form id="messageCoderForm" action=` and disabled it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you are looking for is in the HTML document. Try doing a Ctrl+F search for "buttonSaveAsDraft" to find out where it is linking and disable it there. Links are never created in the CSS file.

As for formatting the CSS, there are a number of sites out there that will make it look nice for you if you copy+paste it in. Check out this site for example: http://www.codebeautifier.com/

Comment: Thanks. I found it at the following code location `<form id="messageCoderForm" action= `  , `buttonSaveDraft` didn't play any role here. Thanks for your help anyways.